# How to make bottom sheet (BottomSheetBehavior) expandable to arbitrary position?

Tags: android, google-maps, bottom-sheet

I have bottom sheet, and I want to change its behavior so it would work like on the main screen of Google Maps application, where you can expand it to any position and leave it there and it won't automatically stick to the bottom or to the top. Here's my layout with bottom sheet:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_gradient_top_shadow"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/map_bottom_sheet" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_bottom_sheet"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:behavior_peekHeight="50dp"
        android:background="@color/lightGray"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

        <include layout="@layout/bottom_sheet_top_buttons"/>
        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_content_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/lightGray"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

What I need in essence is eliminate forcing of *STATE_EXPANDED* and *STATE_COLLAPSED* states when dragging is ended.

Here's a visual explanation of what I try to achieve:
[image]
As you can see, bottom sheet doesn't automatically anchor to the top or the bottom but stays at whatever position it was left.

Comment: Hi, were you able to achieve this behavior? I'm also interested, thanks!

Comment: @dor506 Hi, no, I was working on achieving that but the managers and designers in my team changed the requirements on the fly and decided they need standard bottom sheet behavior :) However I have found out that in order to implement that one needs to reimplement BottomSheetBehavior class; in my case I decided to change the logic of STATE_EXPANDED and assign this state whenever the sheet is visible, not only when it sticks to the top. Or you can rethink it some other way. Anyway, I wish you good luck with implementing this.

Comment: Hey @AlexBerdnikov how about that map scroll on bottom sheet slide ? Can you share it here ?

Comment: @ralphgabb hey, I'm afraid I can't do it now since the project is at my previous job :) I don't have access to it anymore.

Answer (score 6):

Copy the code from `android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior` to make your own custom behavior. Then modify the `onViewReleased()` method which is responsible for the movement of the sheet after the drag ends. You also have to introduce a new state besides the existing ones - the state is helpful to restore the position and let others know in which state your sheet is at the moment with `getState()`.

```
@Override
public void onViewReleased(View releasedChild, float xVel, float yVel) {
    int top;
    @State int targetState;

    // Use the position where the drag ended as new top
    top = releasedChild.getTop();

    // You have to manage the states here, too (introduce a new one)
    targetState = STATE_ANCHORED;

    if (mViewDragHelper.settleCapturedViewAt(releasedChild.getLeft(), top)) {
        setStateInternal(STATE_SETTLING);
        ViewCompat.postOnAnimation(releasedChild, new SettleRunnable(releasedChild, targetState));

    } else {
        setStateInternal(targetState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have created a proof of concept originating from the orginal source code from the design library. You can view it [here](https://github.com/fish-4-fun/like-google-maps/blob/master/README.md). The problem with the original behavior is it doesn't allow flings, and most methods are private so extending the class and overriding some methods in an attempt to achieve it won't get you very far either. My implementation allows for optional snapping behavior, transient states (don't automatically snap after drag) and customizations around setting peek height and max height.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Alex you can try this code for similar expected behaviour, it is not as optimised but it will help you to understand the concept.

```
     final DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
 bottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(200);
// set callback for changes
        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {

                Log.d(TAG, "onStateChanged: " + bottomSheet.getY() + "::" + bottomSheet.getMeasuredHeight() + " :: " + bottomSheet.getTop());

            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {


                ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = bottomSheet.getLayoutParams();
                params.height = Math.max(0, metrics.heightPixels - (int) bottomSheet.getTop());
                bottomSheet.setLayoutParams(params);




            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for your post. It makes bottom sheet go with "steps" when sliding up, so it somehow resembles to the needed behavior but doesn't work as it should. Although, it gives me some ideas for further attempts.

Comment: Yes alex you Need to optimize it, it was a quick logic

Comment: You know, I work on this for two days already and this is a wrong way to implement that. It seems that all you can do is implement your own CoordinatorLayout.Behavior class.

Comment: Hey Alex, I told you earlier this is not the optimized. This is just for your reference.

Comment: No, the thing is you can't optimize it, because BottomSheetBehavior has 4 states for a reason, you have to literally get rid of STATE_COLLAPSED and STATE_EXPANDED states and add fling detection yourself. Tricks and hacks like changing peekHeight won't help, It will be glitching and won'r work smoothly.